# How to implement Session State in ASP.NET vNext MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In Visual Studio 2014, ASP.NET vNext, i am trying to implement Session State in MVC 6.I 
 am not getting any Intellisense in Visual Studio to implement it.Please suggest me how
 to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by "implement session state". Session state is part of the framework, it has already been implemented. Are you trying to _use_ session state? If so, what is not working?

Comment: @Rune,Yeah i am trying to use Session state in MVC 6, and it's not working for me.Means i am not getting Session Property in MVC 6.Like i get ViewBag,ViewData,Cookies etc. in Visual studio 2014 intelisense, But not getting Session.Please tell me how can we make use of it? Thanks.

Comment: I would advise that you don't implement "session state" using application constructs of ASP.NET. Make your site RESTful and persist any session information via content on your pages themselves and your database.

Comment: @ManishKumar I have updated my answer given that ASP.NET vNext has a new session state middleware you can check out.

Answer (score 16):

## Update 11/2/2014

The ASP.NET team has started building a new session state middleware to enable session state in ASP.NET vNext. You can check out the [Session repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Session), which has both the [Session middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Session), as well as a [sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/tree/dev/samples/SessionSample).

To enable session state in an app, call:

```
app.UseSession();
```

And to read/write from it:

```
var some_value = context.Session.GetInt("some_value").Value;
some_value++;
context.Session.SetInt("some_value", some_value);
```

---

## Original answer

Basically same question as [How to do server side state management in vNext Web Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162008/how-to-do-server-side-state-management-in-vnext-web-applications) - session state is not yet implemented in ASP.NET vNext.

As others have noted, TempData is *not* the same thing as Session State, it is merely built on top of it. (And it is also not yet implemented in ASP.NET vNext.)

Comment: Session middleware and sample links are down.

Comment: @Nick-ACNB thanks for the heads up! We moved the source code from the Caching repo to a new Session repo so I updated the links in this post.

Comment: I think you should update your answer since `context`is now written using a capital **C** `Context`and the `GetInt`and `SetInt` function do not exist anymore

Comment: @Tareck117 where are you seeing that it should be capital C Context? And I still see GetInt/SetInt (though there's a discussion about whether they should be changed to GetInt32/SetInt32, but no change has been made).

Comment: Well...I said that because I included the `Microsoft.AspNet.Session` package and using the answer from @Michael Matejko and I was not able to see the context in my controller without using `Context` and the `Context.Session`property is a `ISessionCollection`. But from your comment I guess I'm doing this the wrong way... :)

Comment: @Tareck117 the `context` could be from anywhere, so I deliberately made it lowercase because it's not from a specific property or parameter. If it's in an MVC action then it may very well be `Context` but there are cases outside of MVC. For the GetInt/SetInt extension methods make sure you import the `Microsoft.AspNet.Http` namespace from the `Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions` package. And BTW here's a cool site where you can find out in which package a type/method is located: http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=getint

Comment: You were right, I had not included the `Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions` package and not imported the `Microsoft.AspNet.Http` namespace. Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

I've written a blog post outlining the details of [How to Implement Sessions in ASP.NET 5, MVC6](http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/). **Updated for Beta8**

It boils down to:

- Add `Microsoft.AspNet.Session` nuget package.
- Add `services.AddSession()` to startup.cs
- Add `services.AddCaching()` to startup.cs
- Add `app.UseSession()` to startup.cs
- Use `HttpContext.Session` inside controllers
- Inject `IHttpContextAccessor` to get to the HttpContext outside of controllers

Comment: app.UseInMemorySession doesn't exist in Beta 8

Answer (score 4):

Just install the package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Session
```

and then put

```
app.UseSession();
```

in your Startup.cs. As Eilon pointed out, it will be available via

```
Context.Session.SetString("key", stringValue);
```

Comment: I do not have access to Context in my startup.cs, what namespace does it reside in?

Comment: @Nick-ACNB you can access it in your controller methods