# Session Variables in ASP5/MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC5, I used to use my session variables like this from System.Web

```
PayPalHandler.ExecutePayment(
    Convert.ToString(Session["paymentId"]), 
    Convert.ToString(Session["payerId"]));
```

In ASP5/MVC6, this is no longer an option as `System.Web` does not exist. What is the proper equivalent way of using session variables in the new framework? Documentation is still very scarce.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Session

Comment: I saw this, but it doesn't seem to work the same syntactically and I can't find any usage examples. Do you have an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077298/how-to-implement-session-state-in-asp-net-vnext-mvc-6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to install Nuget package

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Session
```

and use it using Context

```
Context.Session.SetString("Name", "My Name"); //Set
var name = Context.Session.GetString("Name");//Get
```

Good explanation can be found at 
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/270/sessions-in-asp-net-5