# Using Session in ASP.NET 5 beta5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I was trying to use Session ("Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-beta5") in asp.net vnext but i cant.
I have read many comments like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077298/how-to-implement-session-state-in-asp-net-vnext-mvc-6) or [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/270/sessions-in-asp-net-5), but everyone seems to be outdated.

I cant use `Context.Session.SetInt` or `Context.Session.SetString`; I have only available `Context.Session.Set` and do not know how to use its object `ArraySegment<byte>`. Any recommendation?

Comment: Have you read this article http://www.exceptionnotfound.net/session-in-asp-net-5/

Answer (score 1):

The [`ISession` interface](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/6407a1672d92d89c4140fd1e5c07052599d4b97e/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features/ISession.cs) indeed only has a `Set(string key, byte[] value)` overload. `HttpContext` has an `ISession Session` property.

So everything you want to store in the session has to be converted to a byte array. This can be done in many ways, depending on the type:

```
byte[] stringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(someString)
byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(someInt);
```

For complex types, you'll have to use a serializer, for example the BinaryFormatter, as explained in [How to convert an object to a byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446547/how-to-convert-an-object-to-a-byte-array-in-c-sharp).

Luckily there's [some extension methods in `Microsoft.AspNet.Http`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/6407a1672d92d89c4140fd1e5c07052599d4b97e/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions/SessionExtensions.cs) that do this for you:

- `SetString(this ISession session, string key, string value)`
- `SetInt32(this ISession session, string key, int value)`

And of course their respective `Get...` counterparts that convert the byte array back to the relevant type.

All you need is a `using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;` directive in your source in order to be able to use these extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a really interesting article regarding sessions in asp.net 5 and why it's using a byte array to store sessions (*"The main reason behind this decision appears to be to ensure that session values are serialisable for storage on remote servers"*).

Also keep that in mind that **one of the driving forces behind ASP.NET 5 is "cloud-readiness"**

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/270/sessions-in-asp-net-5