# Database Session attribute does not create a one as expected

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core

I created a web api only project with asp.net 5 and trying to set up my NHibernate session management. Everything seems to be fine but inside my controller when I try to use the session, I get a null exception although I mark it with `NHibernateSession` attribute.

I realized that the method does not use the session created by the attribute. What should I do to make it use that one ? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    public ISessionContainer NHibernateSession { get; set; }

    public ValuesController(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet, NHibernateSession]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {

        return _repository.GetProducts(); // session is null exception
    }
}
```

---

```
public class NHibernateSessionAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    protected ISessionContainer sessionContainer;

    public NHibernateSessionAttribute()
    {
        sessionContainer = new NHibernateSessionContainer();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        sessionContainer.OpenSession();
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        sessionContainer.CloseSession();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class NHibernateSessionContainer : ISessionContainer
{
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

    private ISession _session;

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10
            .ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Main.ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
            .BuildConfiguration().BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public ISession Session
    {
        get { return _session; }
    }

    public void OpenSession()
    {
        _session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    public void CloseSession()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _session.Dispose();
    }
}
```

---

```
services.AddSingleton<ISessionContainer, NHibernateSessionContainer>();
services.AddTransient<IRepository, Repository>();
```

Answer (score 0):

session is not enabled by default, did you add it via nuget and configure it for example:

```
app.UseSession();
app.UseInMemorySession(configure: s => s.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));
```

[see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077298/how-to-implement-session-state-in-asp-net-vnext-mvc-6)

Comment: and services.AddSession();

Comment: I am not sure if this session is same as mine but I will give it a try. EDIT: Still same error